# Returning an Int from a subview to the ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a UIView added to my rootViewController, the UIView detects touches and using their coordinates returns me a specific Integer, however I dont know how to return this integer to my rootViewController. I read somewhere that the MVC says that the UIView should not know about the viewcontroller, is this true? if So how might I accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: What about setting up a global data object where you store your integer reading?  Or have the rootview controller read the value from your view -- give it a get method.

Comment: can you give me an example of a Global Data Object?

Comment: Sure, but it looks like you've got a good answer already!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recomend you to define a protocol for passing the Integer between them. Make your view controller implement the protocol and assign it to the view. Then, from the view, fire the protocol method with the desired value.

Protocol example:

```
@protocol YourProtocol

-(void)handleCaptureInteger:(NSInteger)value;

@end
```

View controller (.h) example:

```
@interface YourViewControler : UIViewController<YourProtocol>

...

@end
```

View controller (.m) example:

```
@implementation YourViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [yourView setDelegate:self];
}

@end
```

View example:

```
@interface YourView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSObect<YoutProtocol> *delegate;

@end
```

Comment: This is definitely the best strategy, however having YourView's delegate property be a "retain" property is a mistake and will end up in a memory leak due to a circular memory reference. It should be (nonatomic, assign). The YourView instance is likely retained by the UIViewController, and if the YourView retains the UIViewController neither objects will have their retain counts reach 0 and will never get deallocated. My rule of thumb is that ViewControllers own and retain views, while views have a "weak" (assign) reference to the view controller.

Comment: You are right. I've updated my answer. Thanks for noticing it!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest putting all of this logic on the ViewController. Let the rootViewController add a TapGestureRecognizer to the view, and use its locationInView: and/or locationOfTouch:inView: methods to determine how your application should respond.